# What is the difference between Que and Como?

Tags: gramática, pronomes, conjunções

Can you tell me the difference between **que** and **como**?

For example, the following sentence is right:
Que dia é hoje?

But I would have used **como** instead of **que**.

I've figured out the following website, which lists some rules related to **que** and **como**.
It's Spanish, yes, but I guess the rules related to that interrogative pronouns are the same in that case.

Is that website right?
[https://www.spanishdict.com/compare/qué/cómo](https://www.spanishdict.com/compare/qu%C3%A9/c%C3%B3mo)

Comment: Why would you have thought to use *Como*? What is it that you're trying to say? Are you asking "Which day is it today?" or "What's today's date?", or are you instead asking something more like "How is the day going for you?"

Comment: Maybe your question stems from misunderstanding the difference between "ser" and "estar"?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147339/discussion-on-question-by-cd4user-what-is-the-difference-between-que-and-como); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, I'd like to welcome you to the website. Yes, the website you provided is correct (after all there are many similarities between the Spanish and Portuguese languages, as this is, in fact, one of them).

**When using these two words to introduce a question**, they can be more simply translated to **how/what**:

> - **Que** vou comer? = **What** will I eat?
> - **Como** vou comer? = **How** will I eat?

However, do not be led into thinking these are direct translations; both of these words can be used in many other contexts. To give you an example, the word **Como** as a conjugation has the following uses (from [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.pt)):

> 1. Introduces a comparison, indicating that something is done or happens in the same way as something else (eg: I do this **as** my mother taught me/Eu faço isto **como** a minha mãe me ensinou) **= AS, LIKE**
> 2. Used to introduce the second term in an **equality comparison**, usually preceded by so (eg: she's **as** tall **as** her father = ela é **tão** alta **como** o pai).
> 3. Used in a comparison, preceded by so, to indicate equality or equivalence (eg: I think it was **as** fast **as** it was effective in the solution = acho que foi **tão** rápido **como** eficaz na solução). **= HOW MUCH**
> 4. Indicates someone's perspective or status in relation to something (eg: as a citizen = **como** um cidadão). **= AS, IN THE QUALITY OF**
> 5. Introduce an expression of cause (eg as the store is already closed, we'll be back tomorrow = **como** a loja vai fechar
> 6. ...

The list goes on, but my point is simply this: do not assume how/what are the only two translations of those two words.